# Is it possible for a player to be on two teams at once?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a game in 1.12.2 where players are divided into teams randomly. I'm using `/scoreboard teams join teamA @r` to randomly select players to join a team.

I am wondering, is it possible for a player to be on two teams at once? I am asking this because if the `@r` picks a player on `teamA` already and adds them to `teamB`, the entire map could break.

Comment: also i was not using that command.

Comment: If you were not using that command that I mistakenly assumed, *edit the post to correct the command **from the revised state***, and **do not rollback unless you truly believe that the older revision is better**.

Comment: your revision is not at all what i am doing so i rolled it back since it makes more sense then yours.

Comment: I edited your post to make it more broad and relatable for the community. Why do you think the old version is better? The old version has multiple grammar errors and is slightly unclear. The newer version has no grammar errors, looks clean, and has code font where is necessary. I understand that my revision isn't exactly what you're doing, but these posts on our website are for the community, not just yourself. The fundamental idea is still there, you're asking whether `@r` can pick players already on a team. The other info is irrelevant, and I changed it to make it easier to find.

Comment: I'm not going to rollback your post again because that won't make anything better, instead, if you're willing, let's discuss this proposed change in the [Minecraft chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28/minecraft-talk), so as not to clutter up the comments anymore than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Teams):

> It is important to note that each individual team member can only be on one team; teams cannot share entities.

So the answer to your question is No, but however, if a player is already on a team and you try to assign it to another team, it overwrites the player's previous team. Meaning, if there are some players on `teamA` and you run `/scoreboard teams join teamB @r`, the random selection could pick a team member already on team A, and move them to team B.

You can fix this by making sure that the random selection selects players not on a team, like this:

```
/scoreboard teams join teamB @r[team=]
```

(`team=` selects entities that are not on any team.)

Comment: Thank you, i will put this into my map.